# Debug x86 vs. just Debug

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a weird thing happen to me.  The same solution has always had just Debug to all its projects.  I checked out the entire project again from a few weeks back from Subversion, opened the .sln and built and noticed that now I'm getting a Debug 86 folder and all projects are set to Debug x86 instead of just Debug like they always have been.  Now I don't know if this was changed manually...i sure did not and the point where I checked this out from source control I know did not have x86 at that time.

(I don't know if this makes a diff) I am using IIS 7 in Vista 64-bit with 32-bit processing on the app pool set to false that this application is using because we're running 64-bit in IIS and not using the buit-in VS web server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the history on your project file.  Most likely one of your cohorts altered the project in order to separate the 32-bit and 64-bit debug folders in separate build configurations.